# Label from one grid is overlapping values from another grid

Tags: c#, grid, maui

Currently I have an XML that looks like this:

```cs
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="redacted"
             xmlns:templates="redacted"
             x:Class="redacted">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate">
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Text}" Clicked="UniversalButtonInterface_Clicked" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <templates:StepItemTemplateSelector x:Key="stepSelectorTemplate"
                                            LabelTemplate="{StaticResource labelTemplate}"
                                            ButtonTemplate="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" />

    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
       <StackLayout>
           <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource stepSelectorTemplate}">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        <local:CameraButton/>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Problem is that if label is longer it is overlapping a button from a second grid and I can't get this grid to extend its height. I've tried extending the row definitions but height stays mostly the same and it still overlaps the second grid as if it didn't want to move at all. If I try to apply margin/padding the operations are within the constraints of a height in a grid and the text/button is being cutoff.
Example problem:
[image: button overlapping longer label]

How can I ensure the height of a grid row scales with the label without the overlap?

Comment: Could you please add the `page.xaml.cs` code? This will help me avoid problems caused by overlooking some details of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all ViewCells in ListView have the same height, If you want to only adjust the height of Label ViewCells, you can first set the `HasUnevenRows` property of ListView to `True`:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource stepSelectorTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

Then set the appropriate height for ViewCell and Label:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate">
     <ViewCell Height="xxx">
         <Grid>
             <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                    HeightRequest="xxx"/>
         </Grid>
     </ViewCell>
 </DataTemplate>
```

This is because the `HasUnevenRows` property in ListView controls whether individual viewcell's size can be set. For more specific interpretation, you can refer to [Size items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-8.0#size-items)